# I am getting "The AccountEmail field is required." when passing values to API with FromHeader attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model

I'm trying to get information from a demo database using a RESTful api built in ASP.NET. In order to get information from the database, I need to pass in an object trough the header. However, my API is not receiving those values. My API function is using the [FromHeader] attribute but nothing comes out. I get a 400 status with the following error message: {"AccountEmail":["The AccountEmail field is required."]}

So here is the following code:

I have a model that looks like this:

```
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Account
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Required]
        public long AccountId { get; protected set; }
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string AccountEmail { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Required]
        public Guid AccountAccessKey { get; set; }
    }
}

The API call looks like 

[HttpGet]
        [AccountFilter]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Account>> GetAccount([FromHeader] Account account) {
            try
            {
                return await _Context.GetAccount(account.AccountEmail);
            }
            catch { }
            return BadRequest(new Error()
            {
                ErrorTitle = "Unable to get Account",
                ErrorMessage = "ValidationError"
            });
        }

Where GetAccount looks like 

public Task<Account> GetAccount(string email)
       {
           return _context.Accounts.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.AccountEmail == email);
       }

The API call looks like this

let account = new Account({
            AccountEmail: 'gazefekini@eaglemail.top',
            AccountAccessKey:'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
            AccountId:0
        })

        fetch(process.env.API + '/api/Account/GetAccount', {
            method:'GET',
            headers: {
                "Accept":"application/json",
                "account": "" + account
            }
        })
```

I could use FromQuery and get the account trough the AccountId, but I have a Filter that needs the AccountAccessKey and the AccountEmail to do some AWS verification in the Filter, hence why I decided to pass an account header to the api call.

I tried removing the [Required] attribute to the AccountEmail in the model, and then the API call works, but I need to have a [Required] attribute.

Am I missing something? I understand that the Error is coming from that [Required] attribute but I'm not sure why

Comment: I form headers can be used to bind strings and not sure whether it is possible to bind custom objects will have to use custom bindings. https://www.asptricks.net/2019/04/custom-model-binding-through-header-in.html

Comment: So if you remove [Require] attribute, AccountEmail is empty? and inside AccountFilter, can u put debug there see whether account email is empty or not? Filter will execute before Action.

Comment: It seems like it's not even going trough the filter. It skips it and returns a 400 status

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you need to implement your own model binder.

1. Custom `HeaderComplexModelBinder`

   ```
   public class HeaderComplexModelBinder : IModelBinder
   {
           public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
           {
           if (bindingContext == null)
           {
                   throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
           }

           if (bindingContext == null)
           {
                   throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
           }

           var headerModel = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers[bindingContext.OriginalModelName].FirstOrDefault();
           var modelType = bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ModelType;

           bindingContext.Model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(headerModel, modelType);
           bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(bindingContext.Model);

           return Task.CompletedTask;
           }
   }
   ```
2. Custom `IModelBinderProvider`

   ```
   public class HeaderComplexModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
   {

           public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
           {
           if (context == null)
           {
                   throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
           }

           if (context.Metadata.IsComplexType)
           {
                   var x = context.Metadata as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Metadata.DefaultModelMetadata;
                   var headerAttribute = x.Attributes.Attributes.Where(a => a.GetType() == typeof(FromHeaderAttribute)).FirstOrDefault();
                   if (headerAttribute != null)
                   {
                   return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(HeaderComplexModelBinder));
                   }
                   else
                   {
                   return null;
                   }
           }
           else
           {
                   return null;
           }
           }
   }
   ```
3. Configure in `Startup.cs`

   ```
   services.AddMvc(options => {
           options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new HeaderComplexModelBinderProvider());
   }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
   ```